# jquery-ui ".draggable is not a function", error 

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I am getting the following error (using Firefox 3.5.9):

```
$("#dragMe_" + myCount).draggable is not a function
$("#dragMe_"+myCount).draggable({ containment: 'parent', axis: 'y' });  Line 231 
http://www.liamharding.com/pgi/pgi.php
```

Link to page in question : http://www.liamharding.com/pgi/pgi.php

Once you click the above link, follow along: Click the 2 checkbox's '`R25 + R50 Random Walk`' then click `Show/Refresh Graphs`. Two graphs should be displayed, both with draggable thin horizontal red lines.

Re-open the options panel and de-select `R50 Random Walk`, now click `Show/Refresh Graphs` again, 1 graph is removed and the other updated; now re-select `R50 Random Walk` and click `Show/Refresh`, the `R25 graph` gets updated ok, then the above error occurs and i cant figure out why.

Initially, when displaying the first 2 graphs it uses the same code and it works just fine.

The error occurs on this line:

```
//********* ERROR OCCURS HERE **********
$("#dragMe_"+myCount).draggable({ containment: 'parent', axis: 'y' });
```

Here is the code for the `Show/Refresh Graphs.click() event`:

```
$("#btnShowGraphs").click(function(){
        // Hide 'Options' panel (only if open AND an index is checked)
        if (IsOptionsPanelOpen && ($("#indexCheck:checked").length != 0)) {$('#optionImgDiv').click();};

        var myCount = 0;
        var divIsNew = false;
        var gif_loader_small = '<div id="gif_loader_small"></div>';
        var gif_loader_big = '<div id="gif_loader_big"></div>';

        $("input:checkbox[id=indexCheck]").each(function() {

            if (this.checked) {
                // check for an existing wrapper div for the current forex item, using the current checkbox value (foxex name)
                if ( $("#"+this.value).length == 0 ) {

                    console.log("New 'graphContainer' div : "+this.value);

                    divIsNew = true;
                    // Create new divs for graph image, drag bar and heading
                    var $structure = " \
                        <li id=\""+this.value+"\" class=\"graphContainer\"> \
                            <div id=\"dragMe_"+myCount+"\" class=\"dragMe\"></div> \
                            <div id=\"image_"+myCount+"\" class=\"image\"></div> \
                            <div id=\"heading_"+myCount+"\" class=\"heading\"></div> \
                        </li> \
                    ";
                    $('#graphResults').append($structure);
                    // Hide dragMe DIV
                    $('#dragMe_'+myCount).hide();
                    // Make 'dragMe' draggable div

                    //********* ERROR OCCURS HERE **********
                    $("#dragMe_"+myCount).draggable({ containment: 'parent', axis: 'y' });
                }

                // Display small loading gif
                $(gif_loader_small).clone().appendTo( $(this).parent() );

                // Display large circular loading gif
                var $loader = $(gif_loader_big);
                // add temporary css attributes onto existing graph divs as they need to be displayed diffrently
                if(!divIsNew){

                    console.log("Reposition existing 'gif_loader_big' div");

                    $loader = $(gif_loader_big).css({
                        "position" : "absolute",
                        "top" : "35%",
                        "opacity" : ".85"});
                }

                // add newly styled big-loader-gif to index div
                $loader.clone().prependTo( $("#"+this.value) );

                // Call function to fetch image using ajax
                get_graph(this, myCount, divIsNew);

            } else { 
                // REMOVE 'graphContainer' DIVS NOT CHECKED
                // check for div existance
                if ( $("#"+this.value).length != 0 ) {

                    console.log("DESTROY: #dragMe_"+myCount+", REMOVE: #"+this.value);

                    // DESTROY draggable
                    //$("#dragMe_"+myCount).draggable("destroy");
                    // remove div
                    $("#"+this.value).remove();
                }
            }
            // reset counters and other variables
            myCount++;
            divIsNew = false;

            console.log("Complete: "+this.value+", NEXT index");

        });
    });
```

Comment: Note the script works in Chrome but not Firefox due to the use of the 'console' object without a fall-back for browsers without the feature.

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing the problem in Chrome 5.

Comment: @Geoff, Thanks for your answer, yes it works great in Chrome. Can you elaborate a bit more what you mean by "...but not Firefox due to the use of the 'console' object without a fall-back for browsers without the feature.", do u mean my use of 'console.log' within the above script? If so I added them to debug the problem. Nic.

Comment: Yes, the console object is present in Google Chrome but it isn't part of Firefox. This causes the script to stop execution when I click the "Show/Refresh Graphs" button and so the whole thing wont work at all in Firefox :) A way around this, for future debugging, would be to create a mock object called 'console' with a function within it called 'log', which doesn't have to do anything at all. This will mean it won't stop execution when tested on other browsers, and means you wouldn't have to remove or reinstate the debug console.log lines every time you want to test in another browser.

Comment: @Geoff, in this url  " http://www.liamharding.com/pgi/pgi1.php "  I have removed all 'console.log' calls, the problem still exists !! Now, if I REMOVE the use of 'jquery-ui' for my easing animation & draggable lines over the graphs the page works perfectly in Firefox, as in this url: " http://www.liamharding.com/pgi/pgi2.php ". So something to do with jquery-ui in this page ??? I'm not sure where to go from here! All's well in CHROME.....